# Is there a formula for a cell to return its own row number?

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is a way for a cell to reference its own row number in a formula.

I am using this formula to display text depending on a date that is input.

```
 =(IF($D2="","",(IF($D2=TODAY(),"Due Today!",(IF($D2<TODAY(),(TODAY()-$D2)&" Days Late",IF($D2>TODAY(),"Due in "&($D2-TODAY())&" Day(s)","")))))))
```

Essentially, the workbook moves these entries around to different worksheets based on criteria that is input. However, when the macros move the entries around the cell references become inaccurate. For instance, while the above formula would be correct on the "main page" the D2 reference would become incorrect once the macro moves it to another worksheet.

Is there anyway to reference a cell in such a way where it will change depending on what row it is in? So instead of it looking at "D2" it will look at "DWhateverRowI'mIn"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [Row Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) `=ROW ([reference])` eg `=ROW(D23)` will return row `23`.

Comment: I have tried to work =ROW() into it, but am unsure how to accomplish it. I am looking for a way for the D2 portion of my formula above to automatically "change" itself to instead look for D(Row it got moved to). I may be explaining myself poorly.

Comment: If the macro is moving it to another sheet, then i would say the macro knows where it is putting the formula, you could put this formula in the macro and update it with the cell reference of where the macro is supposed to put the formula.